# Morphophoneme processing library in Java

Tags: nlp, morphological-analysis

Are there any good Java libraries with prebuilt dictionaries that I can use to try and extract word roots from input words?

I asked a more general question which supersedes this question.  It is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2061881/natural-language-parsing-tools-what-is-out-there-and-what-is-not).  Please vote to close this question.

Comment: I had no idea such things existed, but I'd sure love to get my hands on it. (I'm a conglanger and amateur linguist.)

Comment: If there isn't one, would anyone be willing to join forces to write one?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Natural Language Parsing tools: what is out there and what is not?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2061881/natural-language-parsing-tools-what-is-out-there-and-what-is-not)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Work with WordNet for Java in the form of [JWNL](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jwordnet/), which includes a port of Wordnet's "Morphy" lemmatizer.